# Array.length not producing expected result in for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I was doing a question which involves reversing an array. It takes an array as an argument and produces a new array that has the same elements in the inverse order. This is what I came up with at first.

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
var array = [];

for(var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++){
 array.push(fruits.pop(i))
}
console.log(array);
```

The result i ended up getting was `["Mango", "Apple"]` which is not what i was hoping for. So i tried this instead:

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
var array = [];
var count = fruits.length;

for(var i = 0; i < count; i++){
 array.push(fruits.pop(i))
}
console.log(array);
```

This version gave me what I wanted `["Mango", "Apple", "Orange", "Banana"]`. So the only difference between them is that in the first one I use `fruits.length` directly in the for loop and I assign the value of `fruits.length` to `count` in the second one which I then use in the for loop. I don't understand why they produce two different results. Aren't they the same thing? Can someone please help understand what's going on here?

Comment: They are not the same thing, Every time it checks for the condition of the array, once you pop the element from the array gets deleted and the `fruits.length` gets updated.

Comment: fruits.length gets evaluated in every loop, and pop is removing elements from the array

Comment: @ChintuYadavSara I see. Thanks A lot.

Comment: @Phiter Got it. Appreciate the help

Comment: @Elijah check my answer and if it's helpful, tag it as the correct one :D

Comment: @Phiter will do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, `array.length` will be evaluated in every loop, and you're changing the array size every time by -1. Since you're assigning the count to a variable before entering the loop, the variable won't change.

Let's break it down:

Your array has 4 items, your counter is 0.
You iterate once, remove one item from the array and the counter goes up by 1. Now `array.length` is 3.

Same thing happens, now counter is 2 and `array.length` is 2.

When trying to run for the third time, the conditional will not match and the code won't run. That's why the array is having two elements only.

Answer (score 2):

You are removing a fruit from your array i.e. `fruits.pop(i)`, which will decrement the `fruits.length`. Which is then evaluated every time in the loop.

So it makes perfectly sense that your second example works correctly. Here you set the length once and once only.

Answer (score 2):

Using `fruits.pop()` removes the last element from the array, so on the first pass through, `i` = 0 and `fruits.length` = 4, next pass `i` = 1 and `fruits.length` = 3, next pass `i` = 2 and `fruits.length` also = 2 so your `i < fruits.length` check is no longer passing and the loop ends.

In your second example, you are pre-defining the length to equal 4 and that doesn't change as you are removing elements from the array, so the loop continues while `i` < 4.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, [Array.pop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) does not acknowledges any parameter. Hence, `fruits.pop(i)` & `fruits.pop()` are one and the same thing.

**Understanding 1st Loop**

```
for(var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++){
 array.push(fruits.pop(i))
}
```

For **i = 0**, `fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"]`, `fruits.length = 4` -> **i < fruits.length** is **TRUE**, enters loop and pops out 1 value

For **i = 1**, `fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple"]`, `fruits.length = 3` -> **i < fruits.length** is **TRUE**, enters loop and pops out 1 value

For **i = 2**, `fruits = ["Banana", "Orange"]`, `fruits.length = 2` -> **i < fruits.length** is **FALSE**, breaks the loop

---

**Understanding 2nd Loop**

```
for(var i = 0; i < count; i++){
 array.push(fruits.pop(i))
}
```

For **i = 0**, `fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"]`, `count = 4` -> **i < count** is **TRUE**, enters loop and pops out 1 value

For **i = 1**, `fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple"]`, `count = 4` -> **i < count** is **TRUE**, enters loop and pops out 1 value

For **i = 2**, `fruits = ["Banana", "Orange"]`, `count = 4` -> **i < count** is **TRUE**, enters loop and pops out 1 value

For **i = 3**, `fruits = ["Banana"]`, `count = 4` -> **i < count** is **TRUE**, enters loop and pops out 1 value

For **i = 4**, `fruits = []`, `count = 4` -> **i < count** is **FALSE**, breaks the loop

Answer (score 1):

Hm, You are using **`pop()`** method which removes an accessed element from an array after it has been read.

In the beginning, you have 4 elements.

So loop starts to access the last element and removes it from **`fruits`** and then add to a new array.
At next loop length is 3 instead 4.
then length is 2 and this is a place where the loop has not meet the condition for continue.

If you store count number in a variable it will not be affected in latter array count.